# How to install Clang from the binary distribution?

Tags: c++, installation, clang

Clang has a [binary distro](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html), of sorts, but there isn't any `README` file or anything to tell you what's in the tarball or what to do with it.

It appears that I need to separately download and install `libc++`. I may need to copy only the `clang` binary and maybe a few others, but not all the `llvm-*` stuff. This is just judging by the lack of any C++ headers in the binary distro (although some environment-specific headers are included), and the lack of `llvm-as` and such on my existing LLVM 3.2 installation from Xcode.

I just want to run the compiler, not develop with `libclang` or assemble LLVM assembly files. Is there an instruction page somewhere?

Comment: If this is for OS X then when you install any recent version of Xcode 4.x you should already have clang installed, no ?

Comment: How about grabbing the version available from MacPorts?

Comment: @paul I was surprised, but the latest Xcode has only 3.2 (or I'm badly mistaken. Anyway I don't use it.)

Comment: @Jalf Could, but I don't have that installed. I made a fresh OS X install recently and so far have avoided it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter maybe you forgot to install the command line tools option ? With Xcode 4.6.3 and CLT installed I get `clang -v`: `Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)`.

Comment: @PaulR that is exactly what he said: it has only Clang 3.2 (look at the last part. The "Apple LLVM version" is just Apple's made-up number

Comment: OK - got it - thanks - I thought I was using clang 4.2 but evidently not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LLVM project doesn't actually expect many people to use the binary distribution they put out. LLVM does releases for the periodic validation, but it's expected that most users will get LLVM through their OS distro or will build the version they want from source.

See [this email thread](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2013-June/029961.html) where clang developers are discussing how the binaries distrbution is used.

That said, you can use their distribution if you want. What to install depends on what you want to do:

- Use clang as a static compiler.
- Build clang based tools.
- Use LLVM as a backend for your custom language compiler.

> I may need to copy only the clang binary and maybe a few others, but not all the llvm-* stuff.

If all you want to do is compile C/C++/Obj-C, then I believe all you need is the clang binary (and the 'clang++' symbolic link), the 'built-in' headers, and the runtime libraries. You'll find those headers and libs in `/lib/clang/<version>/`. (The clang compiler typically finds its built-in parts by their location relative to the binary.)

If you want to use LLVM as a backend, you'll need either the LLVM headers and libraries to build and link against, or you'll need some of the ll* binaries to process output of your frontend.

If you want to build clang based tools you'll need the clang headers and libraries to build and link against, either the stable C API or the unstable C++ API.

Note that the libraries are built with RTTI and exceptions disabled. This changes the ABI and so you can't link these with code built with RTTI or exceptions enabled.

> It appears that I need to separately download and install libc++.

Correct, libc++ is not included as part of LLVM's distribution. Many of the nominal LLVM subprojects aren't included. LLDB is another example.

Nor does LLVM include a standard C library or the basic Objective-C frameworks.

Comment: Thanks… I've decided to install from source because 3.3 still won't process my program (won't throw a move-only type). Haha, if only they put 1% of the effort of writing that email thread into a `readme` file…

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu/Debian (incuding Linux Mint) based Linux distributions, there are also pre-built .deb files from http://llvm.org/apt/

This has the advantage that it is easer to uninstall at a later point, and also provides Clang 3.4 nightly builds (the 3.3 version is also provided). Simply add one line to your `sources.list` (or use a GUI package manager to do so) and you're set.